# Multiprocessing a for loop in Python stops after a while and the program continues to run using a single thread

Tags: python, linux, numpy, multiprocessing, pool

I am multiprocessing a for loop in Python using Pool in this way:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()   # Create a multiprocessing Pool
    result = pool.map(process_interp, range(ngal))
```

where process_interp is a function I have defined. However, when the number of calculations increase, the program seems to almost crash in a way that a 0 byte file is produced as my result and the Python program continues running but htop shows that it is no longer using multiple threads and only a single thread is being used. For not so heavy calculations, everything just works fine and the program runs fast and correctly.

Can someone please give me insight into what is happening here and what causes this problem? I have no clue how to solve this issue. Thanks a lot!

Edit: This is the function process_interp. Basically calculating some values on a grid. The issue arises when I increase the size of the grid (N_a and N_m) and therefore the number of calculations.

```
def process_interp(k):
    #e = data[k][0]+np.random.normal(0, 0.3, len(data[k][0]))
    e = data[k][0]
    sigma_crit = data[k][1]
    r_s = data[k][2]
    dev_gamma = data[k][4]
    dev_k = data[k][5]
    z_d = data[k][6]
    like_grid = np.empty((N_a, N_m), dtype='longdouble')
    for i in range(N_a):
        for j in range(N_m):
            gamma_nfw, k_nfw = NFWfunc(m_grid[j], z_d, r_s, sigma_crit)
            gamma_dev = dev_gamma*pow(10, alpha_grid[i]-alpha_0)
            k_dev = dev_k*pow(10, alpha_grid[i]-alpha_0)
            mean = (gamma_nfw+gamma_dev)/(1-k_nfw-k_dev)     
            loglike = np.zeros(len(e), dtype='longdouble')
            loglike = -((mean-e)**2/(2*0.3**2))
            like_grid[i,j] = np.prod(np.exp(loglike))
    return like_grid
```

Comment: How heavy is that calculation? Is it possible you run out of RAM? Did you try too set a small Pool size (1 or 2)?

Comment: Interested to know how you're using the range. Perhaps you just need to pass *ngal* then manage the range in *process_iterp*. Perhaps you could show the code for *process_interp*

Comment: Welcome to SO and congrats on your first question.  Please *please* make sure your code is indented correctly when posting Python code :-)  Otherwise good question.

Comment: What is the size of the grid on which it crashes?

Comment: @Klaus D. I will now try a smaller Pool size. The calculations can get really heavy, but shouldn't the program completely crash if I run out of RAM? My program continues running after a while but it is no longer being multiprocessed.

Comment: @DarkKnight I just added the code for process_iterp.

Comment: How the OS reacts to a full RAM can be different. In many cases it will just kill a process. So you could loose one or more of your subproceses.

Comment: @Iguananaut Thank you and sorry about the indents, I will check them from now on. The program runs fine and fast when I have a 200*200 grid, but for a 400*400 grid it almost crashes (in fact it continues running but the multiprocessing stops)

Comment: Klaus D. Thank you. Is there a way I can find out whether a full RAM is causing this problem?

Comment: Which OS do you run?

Comment: @ Klaus D. Red Hat Linux

Comment: Where is `data` defined? This is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If we knew more, we could possibly help more.

Comment: If you look at the kernel ring buffer (`dmesg` command) you will see if a process was killed by the kernel.